# R: parse string to a matrix

Tags: r, parsing

I have a long string (extracted from xml) that look like this (a part):

```
x <- "81 11780 26978 24271 6195\n92 13319 17032 233 16969\n98 17433 13883 6769 18086\n"
```

This is actually a Nx5 matrix of integers. How can I convert this string to a matrix mostly efficient?

`substr(x,26,26)` returns `"\n"`

I'm using R 3.1.2 in Windows x64.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `scan`:

```
matrix(scan(text = x),nrow = 3,byrow = TRUE)
Read 15 items
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]   81 11780 26978 24271  6195
[2,]   92 13319 17032   233 16969
[3,]   98 17433 13883  6769 18086
```

Edited to use `byrow = TRUE`, which is probably what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a a lot! I only use `ncol=5` instead of `nrow` since number of rows is unknown in general.

Comment: @yuk - also worth mentioning is that if you have all integer values, adding `what = integer()` to `scan` will make the read much faster on large text.

Answer (score 2):

`read.table` allows you to transform text into a `data.frame`:

```
df <- read.table(text=x)
```

To get a `matrix`:

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x.split <- gsub(x,"\n","")
x.num <- as.numeric(x.split)
x.matrix <- matrix(x.num,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
```

The first line splits the long character up into a vector with single numbers (still as character). The next line converts to numeric and the last line defines the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- "81 11780 26978 24271 6195\n92 13319 17032 233 16969\n98 17433 13883 6769 18086\n"
#generate data frame
data <- read.csv(textConnection(x),sep=" ",header=F)
#generate matrix
data <- as.matrix(data)
```

Comment: Wow, this is also the great answer! I can convert directly to a data frame, not to a vector. Thanks!

Comment: `textConnection(x)` can be substituted by `text=x`. Don't know if it's faster or not.